# android ndk debugging without cygwin

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-ndk

how to debug a native app without cygwin. I use ndk-build in cmd shell to build the .so library then compile android project in eclipse. cygwin install has caused problem and I consider it as the last resort. is there any way to debug the native code on command line or eclipse? system spec are:
windows 7 prof., latest ndk/sdk/eclipse/mingw.
ndk-gdb exits with 'ndk-gdb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ndk-gdb-py exits with module site not found(when using ndk python)
python ndk-gdb.py gives an error
for d in os.listdir(PYPRPR_GNUSTDCXX_BASE)
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Python27/share/pretty-printers/libstdcxx/*.*' prettyprint is installed on my machine

anoosh

Comment: Try this guide: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for all the responses. basically cdt gives error on nearly everything even primitive parameters such as bool!!! while ndk-build compiles with no problem. now I use fprintf to a file and afterward check where the problems are and try to debug this way. it is a pain but I don't have to deal with cdt/eclipse. I close the ticket

Comment: This is not a good practice. If you want to use printf (and there are many situations that justify this), use `__android_log_print`